Can I remove a table from a schema without physically deleting it and then add it back to a schema?
I have an application that utilizes Advantage Database Server, and I want to migrate it to PostgreSQL.
To remove a table from the database dictionary, I use the following SQL query:
DROP TABLE table_name FROM DATABASE NO_DELETE;

The NO_DELETE keyword instructs the server not to delete the table files from the disk.
After that, I can re-add the deleted table to the database dictionary using the following procedure:
sp_AddTableToDatabase(
  TableName,CHARACTER,200,
  TablePath,CHARACTER,515,
  TableType,SHORTINT,
  CharType,SHORTINT,
  IndexFiles,MEMO,
  Comment,MEMO )

For example:
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_AddTableToDatabase('table_name', 'table_name.adt', 3, 1, '', '');

Is there such a possibility in PostgreSQL?

Move it to another schema
If you need to temporarily "hide" it, you can just move it to a different, non-default schema/namespace:
demo at db<>fiddle
create schema some_other_schema;
alter table table_name set schema some_other_schema;

By default things are created and searched in schema public or whatever schema Postgres sees first in your search_path which means that once you move it elsewhere, it's no longer accessible by anyone unless they explicitly reference it by a fully schema-qualified name.
That should be enough to hide it but to make it truly inaccessible even to those that discover its new location, you can also revoke access to it.
To bring back the table, you can move it back to public:
alter table some_other_schema.table_name set schema public;

And if you also revoked access, you can grant it back.
If you wanted all referential constraints to be broken in the process, possibly to cascade the drop to other objects before bringing this one back, this won't do that. Changing the namespace doesn't affect referential integrity so all foreign keys still point at this table.
Changing schema is a metadata-only operation and will not cause any sort of actual deletion or re-write of the table's pages on disk.
It's worth pointing out that some other RDBMS refer to databases as schemas and namespaces or vice versa. In PostgreSQL, you can have multiple schemas inside a single database and different objects can have the same identifier/name as long as they are in a different schema.

Detach it
If you make it a partitioned table, you can alter table..detach the partition(s), then drop the table. All referential constraints will be broken and the drop will be able to cascade while your actual data in the detached partition remains untouched.
create table your_table
 ( id int primary key
  ,payload text)partition by range(id);
create table your_table_partition partition of your_table default;
alter table your_table detach partition your_table_partition;
drop table your_table cascade;--doesn't affect your_table_partition

Afterwards, you can re-define the table and re-attach the partition(s). All of this is also metdata-only and (except for the cascaded part) doesn't physically delete any rows from table's pages on disk.
create table your_table
 ( id int primary key
  ,payload text)partition by range(id);
alter table your_table attach partition your_table_partition default;


Drop as a foreign object
As mentioned by @Adel Alaa, you can set up the table as a foreign table. If you set it up on a Postgres db, you can use postgres_fdw to link it.
create extension postgres_fdw;
create server linked_local
  foreign data wrapper postgres_fdw;--no options, defaults to all local
create user mapping for current_role
  server linked_local;--again, all defaults
create foreign table f_your_table
 ( id int
  ,payload text)
  server linked_local
  options( schema_name 'public'
          ,table_name 'your_table');

In that case, dropping it means just removing the link to the data, rather than actually removing the data from wherever it actually resides.
insert into f_your_table values(1,'first record inserted via fdw');
insert into your_table values(2,'second record inserted directly');
drop foreign table f_your_table;--dropping foreign table

The drop didn't remove the data at its source:
select * from your_table;




id
payload




1
first record inserted via fdw


2
second record inserted directly



There's file_fdw for things like CSV, extensions that let you link objects from other RDBMS, and many others.

Thank you for your detailed answer! I have one more question. How can I move a specific table from one database to another?
For example, Advantage Database Server allows you to copy the files for a specific table to a folder with another database, then add that table to the database dictionary. If I understand correctly, PostgreSQL does not allow this. How can I correctly move a table in PostgreSQL?

@IvanYuzafatau That's correct, there's no equivalent operation like that in Postgres. If Advantage Database Server implements database isolation like MySQL does, for example, where a database is what Postgres understands as a namespace/schema, then the first example does exactly that: moving the table to another schema in Postgres is the same as moving it to another database in MySQL - in either case it costs no writes, no actual data is being moved.

@IvanYuzafatau If you do want to physically copy things over, you need a client that will connect to both databases and run that operation: Postgres usually comes bundled with pg_dump, pg_restore and psql clients. The command would be something like pg_dump -U user_name1 -d db_name1 --table="table_name" | psql -U user_name2 -d db_name2.

I understood! Thank you so much!

PostgreSQL doesn't allow "re-linking" an external file as a table directly, you must Export then re-create the table.
Search about & try Foreign Data Wrappers (FDW)
Hope it helps
